# Is it ok to set session variable after user creates account, or should I make them login?

Tags: session, php

After a new user creates an account, can I set a `session['id']` or should I make them login to set it?

I'd like to set the session so they can begin setting up the app before waiting for the email validation to get to them. Are there any security issues I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I say no.  I like to send an email to the user's account to authenticate that the email address is valid.  If the user entered credentials in a new account and subsequently verified that email account by clicking on the link in the email message body, I see no need to have the user log in.

The link in the body of the email contains a GET variable with a key, and this key automatically logs the user in for the first time.  You can expire the key so the user only can log in with the key one time.  Subsequent attempts to log in with the key should route to the usual login screen.

You could make it more secure by conditionally skipping the login only if the http request made by clicking on the link in the email contains the cookie set at signup.

What does forcing the user to log in accomplish?  When the user forgets his password you send the "forgot password" reset message with a temporary password to their email account anyway.  So the email is the real authentication in lieu of the login credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - the reason I want to log them in before they validate an email is so they can get started with setting my app before the email gets there. Are there any security holes I'm missing by setting the session here?

Comment: The email is so important to marketing.  Depending upon your app, I would say the email is more important than finishing the signup process.  You can always remind them to finish the signup if you have an email, but vice versa doesn't work.